# Python equivalent for HTTParty

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, httprequest, httparty

I have created an API like project in Ruby on rails using HTTParty gem.Now my boss want me to do the same in Python and I don't know python.So I would like to know is there any equalent gem or default function in Python to generate http requests so easy as httparty.(Remember I am a n00b in python and I am learning even while am typing this question.)

Comment: I don't believe such a thing exists. I was thinking about writing something similar myself, though. I _wish_ there was a Python equivalent...

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing. The closest I've found is [requests](http://python-requests.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). It is one of the best http handling libraries I have used between .Net, Ruby, and Python. It is dead simple.